# Is there a way to make imshow in octave behave more like Matlab?

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm currently migrating some computer vision work I'd previously been doing in Matlab to Octave.  For the most part, it's been a smooth transition, except for one annoyance.

I often use the imshow() procedure to view an image.  In the viewer I get in Matlab, I'm able to inspect individual pixels to see their value.  For example, if I was looking at a connected-components labled image, I could click on a blob and see the actual value of the pixels in it.

Unfortunately, I've not found a way to do this in Octave.  I get a viewing window, but it doesn't seem to have any capability to inspect individual pixels.  Does anyone know how to emulate this behavior in Octave?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have imshow in my matlab (r2007b) or in my octave (no octave-forge). I am going to guess it is image after an imread. try

```
type imshow
```

from matlab to see what's going on internally; if that is the case, I am going to guess you could do

```
F = imread(filename);
image(F);   %to show the entire image
image(F(1:100,1:100));    %to show a corner, etc.
```

you might want to also try pcolor (in matlab, not sure about octave).

hth,

Comment: Imshow is supplied by Matlab's Image Processing Toolbox.  Sorry if I neglected to mention that.